# convert nan value to zero

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have a 2D numpy array. Some of the values in this array are `NaN`. I want to perform certain operations using this array. For example consider the array:

```
[[   0.   43.   67.    0.   38.]
 [ 100.   86.   96.  100.   94.]
 [  76.   79.   83.   89.   56.]
 [  88.   NaN   67.   89.   81.]
 [  94.   79.   67.   89.   69.]
 [  88.   79.   58.   72.   63.]
 [  76.   79.   71.   67.   56.]
 [  71.   71.   NaN   56.  100.]]
```

I am trying to take each row, one at a time, sort it in reversed order to get max 3 values from the row and take their average. The code I tried is:

```
# nparr is a 2D numpy array
for entry in nparr:
    sortedentry = sorted(entry, reverse=True)
    highest_3_values = sortedentry[:3]
    avg_highest_3 = float(sum(highest_3_values)) / 3
```

This does not work for rows containing `NaN`. My question is, is there a quick way to convert all `NaN` values to zero in the 2D numpy array so that I have no problems with sorting and other things I am trying to do.

Comment: `each: map: return isNaN(value) ? 0 : value`

Comment: @kirilloid: sounds good, how about example usage?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

This should work:

```
from numpy import *

a = array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, NaN]])
where_are_NaNs = isnan(a)
a[where_are_NaNs] = 0
```

In the above case where_are_NaNs is:

```
In [12]: where_are_NaNs
Out[12]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

A complement about efficiency. The examples below were run with numpy 1.21.2

```
>>> aa = np.random.random(1_000_000)
>>> a = np.where(aa < 0.15, np.nan, aa)
>>> %timeit a[np.isnan(a)] = 0
536 µs ± 8.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
>>> a = np.where(aa < 0.15, np.nan, aa)
>>> %timeit np.where(np.isnan(a), 0, a)
2.38 ms ± 27.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> a = np.where(aa < 0.15, np.nan, aa)
>>> %timeit np.nan_to_num(a, copy=True)
8.11 ms ± 401 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> a = np.where(aa < 0.15, np.nan, aa)
>>> %timeit np.nan_to_num(a, copy=False)
3.8 ms ± 70.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In consequence `a[np.isnan(a)] = 0` is faster.

Answer (score 200):

Where `A` is your 2D array:

```
import numpy as np
A[np.isnan(A)] = 0
```

The function `isnan` produces a bool array indicating where the `NaN` values are.  A boolean array can by used to index an array of the same shape.  Think of it like a mask.

Comment: I just did this and have `array([0.00000000e+00, 8.12981267e-07, 0.00000000e+00])` so now if I divide 1/array I get `array([             inf, 1230040.64319489,              inf])`

Answer (score 51):

How about [nan_to_num()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)?

Comment: nan_to_num() also changes infinities - this might unwanted in some cases.

Comment: Its also >10x slow than the other methods.

Comment: I wasn't sure about tat ">10x slow" statement so I checked. Indeed, it is that much slower. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: since `v1.17` `nan_to_num` allows what values to fill in for infinites

Answer (score 29):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find where you have `NaN`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[   0,   43,   67,    0,   38],
              [ 100,   86,   96,  100,   94],
              [  76,   79,   83,   89,   56],
              [  88,   np.nan,   67,   89,   81],
              [  94,   79,   67,   89,   69],
              [  88,   79,   58,   72,   63],
              [  76,   79,   71,   67,   56],
              [  71,   71,   np.nan,   56,  100]])

b = np.where(np.isnan(a), 0, a)

In [20]: b
Out[20]: 
array([[   0.,   43.,   67.,    0.,   38.],
       [ 100.,   86.,   96.,  100.,   94.],
       [  76.,   79.,   83.,   89.,   56.],
       [  88.,    0.,   67.,   89.,   81.],
       [  94.,   79.,   67.,   89.,   69.],
       [  88.,   79.,   58.,   72.,   63.],
       [  76.,   79.,   71.,   67.,   56.],
       [  71.,   71.,    0.,   56.,  100.]])
```

Comment: as it is, it doesnt work, you need to change `np.where(np.isnan(a), a, 0)` to `np.where(~np.isnan(a), a, 0)`. This might be a difference in versions used though.

Comment: @TehTris you're right, thanks. I changed it to `b = np.where(np.isnan(a), 0, a)` which is more straightforward then with `~` as I think.

Comment: Although this one is faster than `nan_to_nm`, it is still  slower than the answer of @Marcin. `np.where` is 5 times slower and `nan_to_num` about 8 times.

Answer (score 17):

A code example for [drake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124448/1587329) to use [`nan_to_num`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 3, np.NaN]])
>>> A = np.nan_to_num(A)
>>> A
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [numpy.nan_to_num](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)  :

> numpy.nan_to_num(x) : Replace *nan* with *zero* and *inf* with *finite numbers*.

Example (see doc) :

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=8)
>>> x = np.array([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan, -128, 128])
>>> np.nan_to_num(x)
array([  1.79769313e+308,  -1.79769313e+308,   0.00000000e+000,
        -1.28000000e+002,   1.28000000e+002])
```

Answer (score 1):

nan is never equal to nan

```
if z!=z:z=0
```

so for a 2D array

```
for entry in nparr:
    if entry!=entry:entry=0
```

Comment: This does not work: `entry` is a 1D array, so the test `entry != entry` does not give a simple boolean but raises `ValueError`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use lambda function, an example for 1D array:

```
import numpy as np
a = [np.nan, 2, 3]
map(lambda v:0 if np.isnan(v) == True else v, a)
```

This will give you the result:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -9):

For your purposes, if all the items are stored as `str` and you just use sorted as you are using and then check for the first element and replace it with '0'

```
>>> l1 = ['88','NaN','67','89','81']
>>> n = sorted(l1,reverse=True)
['NaN', '89', '88', '81', '67']
>>> import math
>>> if math.isnan(float(n[0])):
...     n[0] = '0'
... 
>>> n
['0', '89', '88', '81', '67']
```

Comment: Is not your comment bit harsh? I know what numpy is, but did know that array will not be string representation of numbers. I specifically did not give a take to this from numpy perspective but from python's perspective, if that was useful.

Comment: Re-ordering the array just sounds like a confusing way of solving this.

Comment: I need to preserve the order of my array. It won't work if you have multiple 'NaN' in your array.