# Nan to Num Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have multiple array that for those I calculate a linear regression, but sometimes it gives me 0/0 values which gives me a **'NaN'**. I know that to convert an array where there are numbers that are NaN you can convert them using [numpy.nan_to_num](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html). But what if I want to convert a single value **that's not in a array**, but a result of a linear regression [calculation](http://dacharts.org/archives/Ensign_Wiki/Newsletters/tradingtips54_files/54-2.gif)?

EDIT: It's not a duplicate question ([convert nan value to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124376/convert-nan-value-to-zero) ) since I'm referring to a item/result that **is not in a array**

Comment: What is the problem of applying the same reasoning presented for arrays to a scalar value?

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.nan_to_num` works fine on scalars.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.nan_to_num(float('inf'))
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> np.nan_to_num(float('nan'))
0.0
>>> np.nan_to_num(float('-inf'))
-1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Comment: I understand converting `inf` and `-inf`, but when would you ever want to convert `nan` to `0`?

Comment: @AlexBliskovsky In many scenarios when you have a processing pipeline that makes sense only for numbers, and you simply don't care about occasional NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if your variable of choice is NaN with [`math.isnan`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan). If it is, change it to the number of your choice. Like this:

```
>>> import math
>>> x = float("nan")
>>> x
nan
>>> if math.isnan(x):
...     x = 123 # just an example
...
>>> x
123
```

Comment: If OP wants to match `numpy.nan_to_num`'s behavior exactly, this isn't quite right - `math.isnan(float('inf')) == False`, but `numpy.nan_to_num` will convert `float('inf')` to a large number rather than leaving it as is. If OP only cares about actual NaNs, though, this works fine.

Comment: Actually that converted the value. But props for senshin for noticing it (and answering) , and thanks to @Carsten too! Thanks!