# Adding arrays which may contain 'None'-entries

Tags: python, numpy, padding

I have a question regarding the addition of numpy arrays.
Let's assume I have defined a function

```
def foo(a,b):
    return a+b
```

that takes two arrays of the same shape and simply returns their sum. 
Now, I have to deal with the cases that some of the entries may be None.
I would like to deal with those entries as they correspond to float(0), such that

```
[1.0,None,2.0] + [1.0,2.0,2.0]
```

would add up to

```
[2.0,2.0,4.0]
```

Can you provide me with an already-implemented solution?

TIA

Comment: `[1.0,None,2.0]` is a list, not a numpy array.

Comment: Several answers suggest `nan_to_num`.  Look at its code.  It's using `where` (or rather the `where` parameter of `copy_to`) to replace the `nan` with `0`.  (It also handles `inf`.)  You could do that replacement just as easily yourself, and probably faster.

Comment: A 2011 question: [convert nan value to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124376/convert-nan-value-to-zero); and a current question, [Implicitly convert/evaluate NaNs to/as zeros whenever occurs in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50050774/implicitly-convert-evaluate-nans-to-as-zeros-whenever-occurs-in-numpy) trying to do this at a low level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the answer to this is to use an array of floats, rather than an array of arbitrary objects, and then use `np.nan` instead of `None`. NaN has well-defined semantics for arithmetic. (Also, using an array of floats instead of objects will make your code significantly more time and space efficient.)

---

Notice that you don't have to manually convert `None` to `np.nan` if you build the array with an explicit `dtype` of `float` or `np.float64`. Both of these are equivalent:

```
>>> a = np.array([1.0,np.nan,2.0])
>>> a = np.array([1.0,None,2.0],dtype=float)
```

Which means that if, for some reason, you really needed arrays of arbitrary objects with actual `None` in them, you could do that, and then convert it to an array of floats on the fly to get the benefits of NaN:

```
>>> a.astype(float) + b.astype(float)
```

---

At any rate, in this case, just using NaN isn't sufficient:

```
>>> a = np.array([1.0,np.nan,2.0])
>>> b = np.array([1.0,2.0,2.0])
>>> a + b
array([ 2., nan,  4.])
```

That's because the semantics of NaN are that the result of any operation with NaN returns NaN. But you want to treat it as 0.

But it does make the problem easy to solve. The simplest way to solve that is with the function [`nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html):

```
>>> np.nan_to_num(a, 0)
array([1., 0., 2.0])
>>> np.nan_to_num(a, 0) + np.nan_to_num(b, 0)
array([2., 2., 4.])
```

Comment: You could do `a.astype(np.float)` to convert the `None` to `nan`

Comment: @pault Sure. But it's better to construct `a` as floats in the first place. But I'll edit the answer to point that out anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [`numpy.nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html):

```
>>> np.nan_to_num(np.array([1.0,None,2.0], dtype=np.float))
array([ 1.,  0.,  2.])
```

Then,

```
>>> def foo(a,b):
...         return np.nan_to_num(a) + np.nan_to_num(b)
...
>>> foo(np.array([1.0,None,2.0], dtype=np.float), np.array([1.0,2.0,2.0], dtype=np.float))
array([ 2.,  0.,  4.])
```

Comment: You could do `np.nan_to_num(a.astype(np.float)) + np.nan_to_num(b.astype(np.float))` in case redefining the arrays is not an option.

Comment: @pault, thanks for pointing the `astype(np.float)` call out. Fortunately, only one `np.nan_to_num` is required since `NaN` + `anything` = `NaN`.

Comment: @sushain97 No, that's not right. The OP wants to convert `None + 2` into `2`, and presumably also `2 + None` into 2, but you're going to convert both of them to `0` instead.

Comment: Ah, good point. I have modified my answer. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `column_stack` to concatenates both arrays along the second axis then use [`np.nansum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) to sum items over the second axis.

```
In [15]: a = np.array([1.0,None,2.0], dtype=np.float)
# Using dtype here is necessary to convert None to np.nan

In [16]: b = np.array([1.0,2.0,2.0]) 

In [17]: np.nansum(np.column_stack((a, b)), 1)
Out[17]: array([2., 2., 4.])
```