# How to do equivalent of block_reduce on a masked array?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I'm calculating an aggregate value over smaller blocks in a 2D numpy array. I'd like to exclude values 0 from the aggregation operation in an efficient manner (rather than for and if statements).

I'm using `skimage.measure.block_reduce` and `numpy.ma.masked_equal`, but it looks like `block_reduce` ignores the mask.

```py
import numpy as np
import skimage
a = np.array([[2,4,0,12,5,7],[6,0,8,4,3,9]])
zeros_included = skimage.measure.block_reduce(a,(2,2),np.mean)
```

includes 0s and (correctly) produces

```py
zeros_included
array([[3., 6., 6.]])
```

I was hoping

```py
masked = np.ma.masked_equal(a,0)
zeros_excluded = skimage.measure.block_reduce(masked,(2,2),np.mean)
```

would do the trick, but still produces

```py
zeros_excluded
array([[3., 6., 6.]])
```

The desired result would be:

```py
array([[4., 8., 6.]])
```

I'm looking for a pythonesque way to achieve the correct result, use of skimage is optional. Of course my actual arrays and blocks are much bigger than in this example, hence the need for efficiency.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: When working with masked arrays, use masked array functions, or functions that delegate the task to masked methods. Otherwise numpy code (and scipy etc) knows nothing about the mask.

Comment: I haven't used them much, but masked arays tend to less efficient, since they have to track the mask etc.  Look into using the `filled` method to get the appropriate `ndarray`.

Comment: `np.mean(masked[:,0:2])` works because it actually uses `masked[:,0:2].mean()`, the masked mean method.  But the `skimage` `view_as_blocks` (used by `block_reduce`) ignores the array subclassing, producing a regular array (without mask).  So the masking has to be applied to this blocked array, e.g. with a function like: `lambda arr,axis:np.ma.masked_equal(arr,0).mean(axis)`.  Look at the code for `block_reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), but you'll have to modify original array or create a new one:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

a = np.array([[2,4,0,12,5,7],[6,0,8,4,3,9]])


b = a.astype("float")
b[b==0] = np.nan
zeros_excluded = skimage.measure.block_reduce(b,(2,2), np.nanmean)
zeros_excluded

# array([[4., 8., 6.]])
```

Comment: In my actual case, those modifications are no problem. Works great, thanks. For whoever reads this in the future: you'll need to deal with the case where all values in a block are 0. In my case, I set the NaNs to 0 as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124376/convert-nan-value-to-zero)

Answer (score 0):

The core code of `block_reduce` is

```
blocked = view_as_blocks(image, block_size)
return func(blocked, axis=tuple(range(image.ndim, blocked.ndim)))
```

`view_as_blocks` uses `as_strided` to create a different view of the array:

```
In [532]: skimage.util.view_as_blocks(a,(2,2))                                                        
Out[532]: 
array([[[[ 2,  4],
         [ 6,  0]],

        [[ 0, 12],
         [ 8,  4]],

        [[ 5,  7],
         [ 3,  9]]]])
```

When applied to the masked array it produces the same thing.  In effect it works with `masked.data`, or `np.asarray(masked)`.  Some actions preserve subclasses, this does not.

```
In [533]: skimage.util.view_as_blocks(masked,(2,2))  
Out[533]: 
array([[[[ 2,  4],
         [ 6,  0]],
         ...
```

That's why the `np.mean` applied to the (2,3) axes does not respond to the masking.

`np.mean` applied to a masked array delegates the action to the arrays own method, so is sensitive to the masking:

```
In [544]: np.mean(masked[:,:2])                                                                       
Out[544]: 4.0
In [545]: masked[:,:2].mean()                                                                         
Out[545]: 4.0
In [547]: [masked[:,i:i+2].mean() for i in range(0,6,2)]                                              
Out[547]: [4.0, 8.0, 6.0]
```

`np.nanmean` works with `view_as_blocks` because it doesn't depend on the array being a special subclass.

I can define a function that applies masking to the block view:

```
def foo(arr,axis):
    return np.ma.masked_equal(arr,0).mean(axis)

In [552]: skimage.measure.block_reduce(a,(2,2),foo)                                                   
Out[552]: 
masked_array(data=[[4.0, 8.0, 6.0]],
             mask=[[False, False, False]],
       fill_value=1e+20)
```

====

Since your blocks aren't overlapping, I create the blocks with reshaping and swapping axes.

```
In [554]: masked.reshape(2,3,2).transpose(1,0,2)                                                      
Out[554]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[[2, 4],
         [6, --]],

        [[--, 12],
         [8, 4]],

        [[5, 7],
         [3, 9]]],
  mask=[[[False, False],
         [False,  True]],

        [[ True, False],
         [False, False]],

        [[False, False],
         [False, False]]],
  fill_value=0)
```

and then apply `mean` to the last 2 axes:

```
In [555]: masked.reshape(2,3,2).transpose(1,0,2).mean((1,2))                                          
Out[555]: 
masked_array(data=[4.0, 8.0, 6.0],
             mask=[False, False, False],
       fill_value=1e+20)
```