# How to replace Nan value with zeros in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the next array

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,Nan])

>>> a
>>> [1 2 3 Nan]
```

How can I replace the Nan with a zero? i.e.

```
>>> [1 2 3 0]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Edit 2020-10-07: please note that the duplicate answers contain some detailed information regarding nan replacement performance that it may be worth having a look at*

A 5 sec web search gives the answer ...

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

quoting :

```
numpy.nan_to_num(x, copy=True, nan=0.0, posinf=None, neginf=None)
```

> Replace NaN with zero and infinity with large finite numbers (default behaviour) or with the numbers defined by the user using the
> nan, posinf and/or neginf keywords.

Comment: Hey @LoneWanderer , do you want to post your answer in the original post ? This one is quiet interesting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124376/convert-nan-value-to-zero

Comment: @3nrique0 The answer is already in the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899400/9805238