# All entries having nan while using np.nanmean

Tags: python, numpy, nan, mean

How to overcome **division by zero** in the following case:

```
A = 
[[3.0 5.0 nan nan nan]
[nan 5.0 nan 4.0 5.0]
[nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan 1.0 nan 5.0]
[5.0 nan nan 3.0 nan]
[1.0 2.0 nan nan 5.0]
[2.0 nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan 2.0 1.0]
[nan 1.0 5.0 nan nan]
[nan nan 5.0 1.0 nan]]

Mean = np.nanmean(A, axis=1)
```

This produces a division by zero, as `A[2,:]` has all entries as `nan`.

How to return `0` when all values are nan?

Comment: ["_For all-NaN slices, NaN is returned and a RuntimeWarning is raised_"](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html). Seems reasonable. Why not replace remaining nans with 0 afterward?

Comment: If that solves your problem this is mostly the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532201/how-to-replace-nan-value-with-zeros-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: I need mean for each row for which I have to use np.nanmean. Hence can't convert to 0

Comment: _After_ you call nanmean, these bad rows will have np.nan. Correct? If so, you can use `np.nan_to_num` on the _output_ of `nanmean`.

Answer (score 0):

Although using `np.nan_to_num(Mean)` can be used for cleanup, you still get a warning from `np.nanmean`. An alternative is to cleanup the bad rows before feeding them into `np.nanmean`:

```
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
a = np.array([
  [3.0, 5.0, nan, nan, nan],
  [nan, 5.0, nan, 4.0, 5.0],
  [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
])

a0 = a.copy()
a0[np.all(np.isnan(a0), axis=1)] = 0
mean = np.nanmean(a0, axis=1)
```

Result:

`array([4.        , 4.66666667, 0.        ])`