# Deleting NaN values in list in python

Tags: python, list, nan

```
num_A=414
for i in range(1,num_A):
 
    interval = data_A.index[data_A['level'] == i]
    datum = data_A.loc[interval] 
    hyumgi_time=np.max(datum.hyumgi)
    print(hyumgi_time)
```

When I run the code above, `hyumgi_time` gives some `nan` values.
I think `hyumgi_time` is a list. I want to make every `nan` values to 0's.
I think this is a list, not a dataframe. So, I wonder how to make `nan` values to 0's for a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert nan value to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124376/convert-nan-value-to-zero)

Comment: *why* do you think it is a list? And why are you guessing, why not jsut check `type(hyumgi_time)`?

Comment: `data_A` is a dataframe, and `hyumgi` is a column name of `data_A` . However, `hyumgi_time` is not a dataframe. So can I do same as dataframe?

Comment: I printed the `print(type(hyumgi_time))` and it printed out a series of `<class 'float'>`

Answer (score 0):

look at this snippet:

```
df['Set_of_Numbers'] = df['Set_of_Numbers'].fillna(0)
```

for more info - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-nan-values-with-zeros-in-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact: `NaN` is the only value that is not equal to itself. That means you can do this.

```
no_nan = [x if x==x else 0 for x in hyumgi_time]
```

Answer (score 0):

basic method if it is a list:

```
itr = 0
while np.NaN in hyumgi_time:
    if hyumgi_time[itr] == NaN:
        hyumgi_time[itr] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use list comprehension.

```
none_converted = [x if x!=None else 0 for x in a]
```

take a look at it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)