# Add numpy matrices treating SymPy nan entries as 0

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a `numpy` matrix and am trying to find the sum of each row. There are some `nan` entries which I want to treat as `0`. For instance, I would expect the sum of

```
[1, nan, 30]
[nan, 2, nan]
[8, nan, nan]
[nan, 1, 16]
```

to be

```
[31]
[2]
[8]
[17]
```

EDIT: each row contains entries which are either `nan` or a `sympy` `expr`.
So the sum of the row `[x, nan, 30x]` should be `31x`

However, these `nan` values are not `np.NaN`, but are created in calculations with `SymPy` and therefore are [`S.NaN`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#nan).

`np.isnan(S.NaN)` returns `False`. I have tried using `np.nansum` but because of this, it just returns `nan`.

```
A = np.matrix([[1, np.nan, 30],
    [np.nan, 2, np.nan],
    [8, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, 1, 16]])

B = np.matrix([[1, S.NaN, 30],
        [S.NaN, 2, S.NaN],
        [8, S.NaN, S.NaN],
        [S.NaN, 1, 16]])
```

`np.nansum(A, 1)` returns

```
matrix([[31.],
        [ 2.],
        [ 8.],
        [17.]])
```

as expected.

But `np.nansum(B, 1)` returns

```
matrix([[nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan]])
```

I also thought that I might be able to replace the `S.NaN` values with `0`. There are quite a lot of answered questions about how to convert `np.NaN` values to `0`, e.g. [convert nan value to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124376/convert-nan-value-to-zero.), but these solutions don't work because I don't think there's an equivalent in SymPy for `np.isnan()`.

Is there either an equivalent in SymPy for `np.nansum` which I could use, or a way to replace `S.NaN` values with `0` (or `np.NaN`)?

Comment: Generally it isn't a good idea to mix numpy and sympy.  There are too many things like this that don't work.

Comment: Even if it were just in sympy, would there be a way to add the matrices as described?

Comment: You'd have to use `sympy.Matrix` or something like that.

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to find out _is there an equivalent in SymPy for `np.nansum` which I could use_

Comment: You can search the `sympy` docs just as well as I can.  Here's the main `nan` section, https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=nan#sympy.core.numbers.NaN

Comment: Yes, I did look there and thought there wasn't an equivalent but I wasn't certain. I've realised that I've not been clear in my question or the examples though, so I apologise: the values in the matrix are not all floats (in fact, they are all either `sympy` expressions or `nan`); I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with `sympy.Matrix`, but turns out it isn't needed.

A numpy array with `sympy.nan` elements.  Note the object dtype:

```
In [65]: arr
Out[65]: 
array([[1, nan, 30],
       [nan, 2, nan],
       [8, nan, nan],
       [nan, 1, 16]], dtype=object)

In [66]: type(arr[0,1])
Out[66]: sympy.core.numbers.NaN
```

It converts to a float array without problem:

```
In [67]: arr.astype(float)
Out[67]: 
array([[ 1., nan, 30.],
       [nan,  2., nan],
       [ 8., nan, nan],
       [nan,  1., 16.]])

In [68]: type(_[0,1])
Out[68]: numpy.float64

In [69]: np.nansum(__,1)
Out[69]: array([31.,  2.,  8., 17.])
```

`sympy.nan` converts to python float without problem:

```
In [71]: type(nan)
Out[71]: sympy.core.numbers.NaN

In [72]: type(float(nan))
Out[72]: float
```

### sympy.Matrix

If I make a `sympy.Matrix` from the array:

```
In [83]: M= Matrix(arr)

In [84]: M
Out[84]: 
⎡ 1   nan  30 ⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢nan   2   nan⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎢ 8   nan  nan⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣nan   1   16 ⎦

In [85]: M[0,1]
Out[85]: 
nan

In [86]: type(M[0,1])
Out[86]: sympy.core.numbers.NaN
```

I can use `subs` to replace the `nan`:

```
In [87]: M1 = M.subs({nan: 0})

In [88]: M1
Out[88]: 
⎡1  0  30⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎢0  2  0 ⎥
⎢        ⎥
⎢8  0  0 ⎥
⎢        ⎥
⎣0  1  16⎦
```

`np.sum` works on this:

```
In [89]: np.sum(M1,1)
Out[89]: array([31, 2, 8, 17], dtype=object)
```

Presumably `np.sum` first turns the `Matrix` in to an array:

```
In [90]: np.array(M1)
Out[90]: 
array([[1, 0, 30],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [8, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 16]], dtype=object)
```

### ==

We don't need `isnan` to test for `sp.nan`.  While its `float` value is `np.nan` (or python `nan`), it's a distinct `sympy` object, and `==` works just fine (that's shown in the `sympy.nan` docs).

```
In [92]: arr==sp.nan
Out[92]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]])

In [93]: arr1 = np.where(arr==sp.nan,0,arr)

In [94]: arr1
Out[94]: 
array([[1, 0, 30],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [8, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 16]], dtype=object)
```

or if you insist on using `nansum`:

```
In [95]: np.nansum(np.where(arr==sp.nan,np.nan,arr),1)
Out[95]: array([31, 2, 8, 17], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the function `np.nditer` which allows you to iterate through each entry in an array. Using the fact that `S.NaN` raises a `TypeError` when a comparison is made, the following code correctly replaces any entries of it with a `0` (or anything else)

```
In[122]: B
Out[122]: 
matrix([[1, nan, 30],
        [nan, 2, nan],
        [8, nan, nan],
        [nan, 1, 16]], dtype=object)

In[123]: for x in np.nditer(B, flags=["refs_ok"], op_flags = ['readwrite']):
    try:
        x > 0
    except TypeError:
        x[...] = 0
        

In[124]: B
Out[124]: 
matrix([[1, 0, 30],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [8, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 16]], dtype=object)
```